# Facebook application doesn't work in IE(Redirecting to the host Canvas Callback URL)

Tags: php, facebook, internet-explorer, browser

I have a file named fbmain.php which do all facebook authentication parts. And I have a button in index.php file which passes data to a.php file
This is just an example

```
//fbmain.php : do all facebook authentication parts

//index.php
      <?php
           include_once "fbmain.php";
       ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://myserver/a/a.php" method="POST">
     //Some codes 
     <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

In a.php file I have to include fbmain.php again since here I do some api call.

```
  //a.php
<?php    
    include_once "fbmain.php";

        //some codes            
            try{            
                $me = $facebook->api('/me?access_token='. $token); 
                print_r($me);               
            } catch(FacebookApiException $e){
                echo "Error:" .$e;
            }
?>
```

THis app works fine in firefox browser but **doesnt work in IE(When the user click 'Upload button it redirect user to the host Canvas Callback URL').**

I tried placing bellow codes at the top of in each and every file(fbmain.php, index.php, a.php). But it still doesn't work?

First I tried this

```
header('P3P: CP=HONK');
ob_start();
```

Then I tried this

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');    
ob_start();
```

**But nothing works in IE.** 
Can anyone please help me?

//fbmain.php file

```
<?php
    //header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
    header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
    ob_start();
    //facebook application
    //set facebook application id, secret key and api key here
    $fbconfig['appid' ] = "MY_APP_ID";      
    $fbconfig['api'   ] = "MY_API_KEY";
    $fbconfig['secret'] = "MY_APP_SECRET";

    //set application urls here
    $fbconfig['baseUrl']    =   "http://MYSERVER/uploader/index.php"; //http://thinkdiff.net/demo/newfbconnect1/iframe;
    $fbconfig['appBaseUrl'] =   "http://apps.facebook.com/approne"; //http://apps.facebook.com/thinkdiffdemo;

    $uid            =   null; //facebook user id

    try{
        include_once "facebook.php";
    }catch(Exception $o){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($o);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    // Create our Application instance.
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
      'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    //Facebook Authentication part
    $session = $facebook->getSession();

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
            'canvas'    => 1,
            'fbconnect' => 0,
            'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_photos'
            )
    );
    if (!$session) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    } 
    if ($session) {
        try {
            $uid      =   $facebook->getUser();
                //Has a loading problem
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
            exit;
        }       
    }

    $signed_request = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
    $secret = $fbconfig['secret'];
    $data = parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret);
    $fan_page_id = $data['page']['id'];
    $admin_check = $data['page']['admin'];

        //Get fan page id
    function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {

        list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

        // decode the data
        $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
        $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

        if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
            error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
            return null;
        }

        // check sig
        $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
        if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
            error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
            return null;
        }
        return $data;

    }

    function base64_url_decode($input) {
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
    }   

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar issue with IE before where the user session was not persisting server side. To get around it I added a hidden field to forms served to IE containing the `signed_request`.

```
<input type='hidden' name='signed_request' value='VALID_SIGNED_REQUEST' />
```

But this solution should work with the `code` parameter or by passing the authorisation token and then using it to restore the users session server side. You can also try maintaining your own session cookie.

---

I see you are using the pre v3 of the PHP SDK. So you should try adding the hidden field:

```
<input type='hidden' name='session' value='<?php echo json_encode($session); ?>' />
```

Comment: I added facebook signed_request code to the fbmain.php file and pass it to the a.php file from inde.php file using a hidden field.Now what should I do next?

Comment: If you were having the same problem as I was, the post should be accepted without the redirect being performed. I assume you're using a valid signed request.

Comment: Which version of the PHP sdk are you using? Is this a canvas or tab issue?

Comment: When the user click the upload button browser goes  to the a.php file and after few seconds it is redirected back to the index.php file again(If I didn't include the fbmain.php file, it stop redirecting)

Comment: Can you put the source for fbmain.php in your question? Also can you give a link to your application?

Comment: I have made some changes in my app. So it may not look nice :)
I have added my fbmain.php file.

Comment: Now I am having same problem for the next file. a.php file runs without redirecting. At the end of that a.php file I load another file named b.php using script 'window.location =URL' method. In that file also I have include fbmain.php file and it redirect the page.I tried passing $session variable to b.php file.but this time seems like it doesn't work? Can you help

Comment: Does the second session variable actually contain a valid value? You can also try creating your own session cookie with the session data.

Comment: Yes it has a valid value. If I use a button to send the session($_POST) it works fine. I used '$_SESSION['session'] = $session;' to pass the session value.But doesn't work.How can I create my own session cookie?